# Difference between Finder filename and Name/extension in Info

Tags: finder

By chance I found that for some folders and files the names, as they appear in Finder, are different from their actual names, found in the file's info under "Name & Extension". E.g. I have a folder called "Open Wipe" in the Finder listing but "40183A33-91F8-42A4-A899-E3C98D391629.localized" in "Name & Extension".

Normally this would be of no concern to me, I guess, but since I am using an online backup service (iDrive in my case), these files appear in the created backup under their "Name & Extension"-name and NOT under their Finder-name. This makes locating these files in the backup virtually impossible, I would say....

Does any of you have an advice how to deal with this ?